# Forcing Date() constructor argument time zone interpretation

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I have an use case where I use input from the user, which is on the form `YYYY-MM-DD'T'TT:mm` to create a `Date` object in Javascript. The problem is that Firefox and Chrome interpret the input as the local time (which is what I want), whilst Safari interprets the input as UTC time and converts it to local. How do I force Safari to use the same interpretation of the input as the other two?

Comment: You can't, you should not use the built-in parser to parse strings, see  [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) You can write a simple parser for a single format in about 4 lines of code, or use a library.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to parse the string yourself (it's trivial, after all) and use the multiple-argument `Date` constructor, which always works in local time. Or use a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to do it for you. I was tempted to suggest adding a timezone offset (`+0400`, etc.) to the string (based on `getTimezoneOffset` on a `Date` object), but determining the right timezone offset requires that you know the date/time (because of Daylight Savings Time), and so...you'd have to do the work anyway.